# check for question mark in input to web service

Tags: java, web-services

I have a web service. It has fields that are optional.

Now when the user test it in `SOAP-UI`, he is passing default values, i.e. `"?"`

```
<!--optional>
<name>?</name>
```

I want to put the check at xsd/wsdl level to prevent this type of requests from hitting my service.

I m using axis2 to host my service.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1):

This will only allow lower/uppercase letters from a-z / A-Z for a String-based value:

```
<xs:element name="your_element">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Just google a bit about "XSD" or "XML Schema", read a few pages and you can restrict/ allow basicially anything ;)